# Is there a way to programmatically extract table references from an Oracle package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

Several times a year, my team will write a new Oracle package for some reason or another, and much of the time this package only references tables that the package (user/role that our packages run as) already has grants for.

Occasionally, this isn't the case. The package is checked in, it fails to compile, and we get a cryptic error message with a line number in the vicinity of the table name.

The trouble is that at this point, we will wait several hours for the (political) approval process to play out, the grant is given, we check the package in... and it fails with a new table name.

Is there a way to get a list of all references programmatically? If so, we could automate it to check against dba_tab_privs to see if grants will be needed beforehand, or even generate the grant script to make things easier on the team that actually doles out those grants (especially months later, when it gets deployed to production and we go through the whole sorry mess once again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that all the references are static (i.e. you don't have bits of random dynamic SQL in your code), you can query `dba_dependencies'

```
select referenced_owner, referenced_name
  from dba_dependencies
 where owner = <<owner of package>>
   and name  = <<name of package>>
   and type  = 'PACKAGE BODY'
   and referenced_type = 'TABLE'
```

You could look for non-table references as well or dependencies related to the package specification as well as the package body if you'd like.  This will just show cases where the package body depends on a table.

Comment: Dang they don't give me permissions on dba_dependencies!

Comment: @Gary_W - You might be able to use `all_dependencies` or `user_dependences` depending on the assumptions you can make.  If you're thinking of using `dba_tab_privs` to automate the grants that need to be made, though, I'd think that you could ask for privileges on `dba_dependencies`.

Comment: Sweet!  ALL_DEPENDENCIES works.  This is a new one for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ALL_SOURCE table.  You can query against the TEXT column for what you are looking for.

```
select *
from all_source
where type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
and owner = 'XYZ'
and name = 'YOUR PACKAGE NAME'
order by line;
```

Edit: Justin Cave's answer is the correct one, but I'll leave this here for info anyway as every little bit of info helps.